# NSCalendarUnitDay shows the current day as a single digit int. How can I make it 2 digits such as "03"?

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nscalendar

So I'm creating a date string in MMyy format:

```
        var components: NSDateComponents!
        components = calendar.components(.CalendarUnitYear | .CalendarUnitMonth | .CalendarUnitDay, fromDate: NSDate()) as NSDateComponents
        let stringDate = "\(components.month)\(components.day)" // "113"
```

If a day is less than 10 then I get a 3 digit number as a string.

How do I change things so that I get a 4 digit number as a string instead e.g. "1103"?

Comment: I would have never typed in "leading zeros for int in swift" to be honest. But the answer below sorted things out.

Comment: "Leading zeros" is a common term for what you wanted. A complete description of the print formats can be found here: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html. – Alternatively, you could use a NSDateFormatter in your case.

Comment: Thanks. I will make note of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ObjectiveC it will be

```
NSString *strDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d%02d", components.day, components.month];
```